# Configuring hadoop-2.0.2-alpha with hbase-0.94.2

Tags: hadoop, hbase

> if i try to start the hbase, hmaster is not running and getting below
>   error.From google i tried it is because of classpath mismatch so i
>   copied hadoop jar into hbase/lib,But still i am getiing below error.

```
FATAL master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 7 cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy10.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:344)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Classpath error try to add `$HBASE_HOME/conf/` and `$HBASE_HOME/lib/` to your `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. That latter one can be set in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh`. For me it works that way.